# How to fix the Alljoyn iOS SDK build failed with following error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, alljoyn

Does anybody have idea about fixing the below issue?

> scons: Entering directory `/Users/ajchandra15/Documents/Developer/Framework/alljoyn-ios/alljoyn/alljoyn'
>   scons: Reading SConscript files ...
>   Checking c++ compiler support for -std=c++11 flag... (cached) yes
>   Using debug settings for darwin build...
>   Using flags for iOS simulator...
>   debug
>   Using iOS debug configuration
>   Using OpenSSL crypto
>   Building bindings: cpp, c, java, js
>   Building services: 
>   GTEST_DIR not specified skipping common unit test build
>   Not building unit tests for iOS...
>   GTEST_DIR not specified skipping alljoyn_c unit test build
>   JAVA_HOME not set
>   Command /usr/local/bin/scons failed with exit code 1

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're building the Alljoyn binding for Java (together with c++, c and js) then you have to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable otherwise `scons` is not able to find the java compiler.

Comment: I already added _java_home_ path to my os environment variables, though it is throwing same error.

Comment: it should be something like this: `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun"` and `export CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java/junit4.9.jar"`

Comment: I couldn't find any directories as you mentioned, the path may be in windows version but i'm using mac

Comment: the directory I mentioned were only examples.You have to find out on your mac where 1) the java directory is, 2) the junit4.9.jar is

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of XCode 7 do not inherit environmental variables. You'll have to add a custom user-defined variable for JAVA_HOME.

To find your java path, type ">which java" on the terminal.

Reference for Xcode env variables: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8451